# AsyncController OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache, asynccontroller

When implementing an [asynchronous controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) action in ASP.NET MVC, if I want to output cache the `ActionResult`, which method do I put the `OutputCache` attribute on?

```
public class PortalController : AsyncController {
    /// HERE...?
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 30 /* 30min */, VaryByParam = "city")]
    public void NewsAsync(string city) {

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
        newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = e.Value;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
        newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
    }

    /// ...OR HERE?
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 30 /* 30min */, VaryByParam = "city")]
    public ActionResult NewsCompleted(string[] headlines) {
        return View("News", new ViewStringModel
        {
            NewsHeadlines = headlines
        });
    }
}
```

At first, I assumed that it would go on `NewsCompleted`, because that is the method which returns an `ActionResult`.

Then I realized that `NewsAsync` is associated with `VaryByParam`, so it probably makes more sense to put the attribute on that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `OutputCache` parameter goes on the `void NewsAsync` method, not the `ActionResult NewsCompleted` method.  (determined by experimentation)